# VBA Excel Show Values in MSGBOX

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a simple Sub that grabs a range of data and displays it in a MSGBox. When I run the code I receive a Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range. Could some one assist?

```
Sub main()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim searchContent As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim txt As String

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
searchContent = ws1.Range("B2:B11").Value

For i = 1 To 10
    txt = txt & searchContent(i) & vbCrLf
Next i

MsgBox (txt)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Range` when converted to an array is 2 dimensional so you end up with `searchContent(1 to 10, 1 To 1).`

To read this in your loop:

```
txt = txt & searchContent(i, 1) & vbCrLf
```

Comment: Thanks that did it!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your Array as one-dimension (since you are trying to read a single column Range), you can use the `Application.Transpose` :

```
Sub main()

Dim ws1                 As Worksheet
Dim searchContent       As Variant
Dim i                   As Integer
Dim txt                 As String

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

searchContent = Application.Transpose(ws1.Range("B2:B11").Value)

For i = 1 To UBound(searchContent)
    txt = txt & searchContent(i) & vbCrLf
Next i

MsgBox (txt)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution!